# AddDistanceConstraint() in Multibody Plant?

Tags: drake

I am trying to implement a distance constraint between two point bodies, but when I try to use the AddDistanceConstraint() function I get the following error:

'MultibodyPlant_float' object has no attribute 'AddDistanceConstraint'

Here is the code I am using:

```
    builder = DiagramBuilder()
    compass_walker, scene_graph = AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph(builder, time_step=0.0)
    Parser(compass_walker).AddModelsFromString(urdf, ".urdf")

    anchorpoint = compass_walker.GetBodyByName("anchorpoint")
    anchorpoint_vector = np.array([0, 0, 0])

    ground_mass = compass_walker.GetBodyByName("ground_mass")
    ground_mass_vector = np.array([0, 0, 0])

    anchor = compass_walker.AddDistanceConstraint(
                anchorpoint,
                anchorpoint_vector,
                ground_mass,
                ground_mass_vector,
                0.01,
            )
```

I've tried importing AddDistanceConstraint() but was unsuccessful. I've also tried to add the constraint without referencing the Multibody Plant: `anchor = AddDistanceConstraint(...)` but this also did not work.

Comment: For the record, what version of Drake are you using? The bindings for that function went in four months ago ([release v1.15.0](https://drake.mit.edu/release_notes/v1.15.0.html)).

Comment: Ah, that might be it. I am using a deepnote notebook with a docker file whose environment cache was created 5 months ago. I will look into updating the Drake version. Thanks!

Comment: Was this your problem? if so, could you mark your question as answered? maybe even update the description describing your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using an older version of Drake (needed v.1.15.0 or newer). It is worth mentioning that currently distance constraints are only supported for discrete MultibodyPlant models.